# elasticsearch tokenizes facet terms

Tags: elasticsearch, faceted-search, facet

I am using elasticsearch to filter products by certain criteria on the category page. 
One option is to filter by the manufacturer. The user can choose the manufacturer name and gets a filtered resultset. My problem is that elasticsearch seems to tokenize the facet terms although the mapping is defined as "not_analyzed".

See the following example:

My mapping looks like this:

```
POST /products_test/product
{
    "mappings" : {
        "product":{
            "properties":{
                "manufacturer": {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "index" : "not_analyzed"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my test data:

```
POST /products_test/product/1
{
    "id": 1,
    "manufacturer": "bra"
}

POST /products_test/product/2
{
    "id": 2,
    "manufacturer": "abracada bra"
}
```

If I execute the following query I get one hit but two terms for the facet:

```
POST /products_test/_search
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match_all": {}
         },
         "filter": {
          "term": {
             "manufacturer": "abracada"
          }
         }
      }
   },
   "facets": {
      "f_manufacturer": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "manufacturer",
            "size": 30,
            "order": "term",
            "all_terms": false
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Result:

```
   "facets": {
      "f_manufacturer": {
         "_type": "terms",
         "missing": 0,
         "total": 2,
         "other": 0,
         "terms": [
            {
               "term": "abracada",
               "count": 1
            },
            {
               "term": "bra",
               "count": 1
            }
         ]
      }
   }
```

What I expected was to get a single facet term with "abracada bra" as value.

Comment: It seems no problem there. However, i suggest you to check your mapping twice. There might be something that u miss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mapping and the behavior you expect from it is correct.

There is most likely something else amiss here, so you should check whether you actually have the assumed mapping.

For example, your term filter (`{"term": {"manufacturer": "abracada"}}`) does *not* match "abracada bra".

Here is a runnable example you can play with: https://www.found.no/play/gist/cf4e908967e6512bc3b2

```
export ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT="http://localhost:9200"

# Create indexes

curl -XPUT "$ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT/products_test" -d '{
    "settings": {},
    "mappings": {
        "product": {
            "properties": {
                "manufacturer": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'


# Index documents
curl -XPOST "$ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT/_bulk?refresh=true" -d '
{"index":{"_index":"products_test","_type":"product","_id":1}}
{"manufacturer":"bra"}
{"index":{"_index":"products_test","_type":"product","_id":2}}
{"manufacturer":"abracada bra"}
{"index":{"_index":"products_test","_type":"product","_id":3}}
{"manufacturer":"abracada"}
'

# Do searches

# Note: The filter is for "abracada bra" and not "abracada"
curl -XPOST "$ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT/_search?pretty" -d '
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                    "manufacturer": "abracada bra"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "facets": {
        "f_manufacturer": {
            "terms": {
                "all_terms": false,
                "field": "manufacturer",
                "order": "term",
                "size": 30
            }
        }
    }
}
'

curl -XPOST "$ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT/_search?pretty" -d '
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                    "manufacturer": "abracada"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "facets": {
        "f_manufacturer": {
            "terms": {
                "all_terms": false,
                "field": "manufacturer",
                "order": "term",
                "size": 30
            }
        }
    }
}
'
```

Comment: You were correct. I had made a mistake while creating the mapping for the document and the "not_analyzed" part was not set.